# Why do I get a "Bad handler AWS Lambda - not enough values to unpack" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to execute a Lambda function but I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Bad handler 'AlertMetricSender': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MalformedHandlerName",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

My Lambda handler is specified in `AlertMetricSender.py`:

```
from modules.ZabbixSender import ZabbixSender
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sender = ZabbixSender("10.10.10.10", 10051)
    sender.add("Zabbix server", "lambda.test", 5.65)
    sender.send()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**This is normally caused by an incorrect value specified for the "Handler" setting for the Lambda function.**

It is a reference to the method in your function code that processes events i.e. the entry point.

[image]

The value of the handler argument is comprised of the below, separated by a dot:

- The name of the file in which the Lambda handler function is located
- The name of the Python handler function.

**Make sure you have not missed the filename.**

In this case, it looks like the handler should be set to `AlertMetricSender.lambda_handler`.

Comment: Hm that was the issue. I named it `AlertMetricSender` but is should have been `AlertMetricSender.lambda_handler`.

Comment: As `AlertMetricSender` can have multiple methods, it makes sense why it needs to be more drilled down - glad it's sorted

Comment: Thanks. I was deploying this through CDK, and even for me this ended up being the right answer. Had no idea what filename CDK was defaulting to (likes index.py apparently). You're my hero. Can't believe it was so simple or took me so long.

Comment: @JohnO Hey John, no worries! Not a hero at all but glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

## If you're using Docker & Submodules

In my case, I'm using a custom-built docker image, and my handler is inside of a submodule.

This is what I had originally at the bottom of my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD ["parent_module.main.lambda_handler"]
```

Instead of a python-style import path (`<parent_module>.<sub_module>.<function_name>`), the `CMD` format is actually `<filepath>.<function_name>`. That means the parent module and child module need to be separated by a `/`, not a `.`. This is what worked for me:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD ["parent_module/main.lambda_handler"]
```